# How to view the first 2 rows in to single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to view the first 2 rows in to single row

**Table1**

```
id  name     value size   result
----------------------------------
001 rajan    100   280DD   100%
002 Vijayan  200   120DD    80%
003 Sidarth  300   150DD    90%
004 Rakesh   400   270DD    95%
...
```

I want to select first 2 row in to single row....

Expected Output

```
id id name name value value size size result result
---------------------------------------------------------    
001 002 rajan vijayan 100 200 280DD 120DD 100% 80%
003 004 Sidarth Rakesh 300 400 150DD 270DD 90% 95%
.....
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t.Id, tt.Id, t.name, tt.name, t.value, tt.value, t.size, tt.size, t.result, tt.result
FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN YourTable tt ON tt.Id = t.Id + 1
WHERE tt.Id % 2 = 0
```

That works for me. Hope it help you.

Please try that if you stil need help.

```
Declare @TempTable as table (FirstId int, SecondId int null, FirstCaption nvarchar(max), SecondCaption nvarchar(max) null, FirstDescription nvarchar(max), SecondDescription nvarchar(max) null)
```

DECLARE @TempId int
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ID FROM Categories
open curs 
fetch next from curs into @TempId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    IF (@TempId % 2 = 1)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @TempTable
            SELECT 
                t.Id, null, t.Caption, null, t.Description, null
            FROM categories t
            WHERE t.Id = @TempId

```
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @TempTable SET SecondId = t.Id, SecondCaption = t.Caption, SecondDescription = t.Description
        FROM categories t
        INNER JOIN @TempTable tt ON tt.FirstId = @TempId - 1
        WHERE t.Id = @TempId
    END
fetch next from curs into @TempId
```

end
close curs
deallocate curs

SELECT * FROM @TempTable

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: This will give `1,2` and `2,3` and `3,4`, etc.  You need `WHERE (t.id % 2) = 1`, or something to ensure `t` only includes rows `1, 3, 5, etc`

Comment: @Radislav, it is coming like 1,1 and 3,3 and 5,5..., i need 1,2 and 3,4 and 5,6 and 7,8....

Comment: I readly don't why, for me it works perfectly. I have tried it again. Do you have any other conditions in your query?

Comment: @Radislav, you query is working if i have even record, incase i am having only one record means, nothing displaying or if i have 3 record means 1,2 is displaying or if i have 5 record means 1,2 and 3,4 is displaying, 5 is not displaying, plz can you check you query....

Comment: That should work. Please try it if you stil need help. I have updated my unswer. But formatting is not good :(

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
select row_number() over (order by id) as rn,
* from Table1
)
select a.id, b.id, a.name, a.value, b.value, a.size, b.size, a.result, b.result
from cte a join cte.b on a.id = b.id - 1

where a.rn <insert your criteria for which to show, for example in (1,3,5,7) or a modulus operator to see every 2nd row to avoid duplicate data>
```

Comment: The question is marked as `sql-server-2000`, which doesn't support common table expressions.

Comment: o. i didn't see the 2000 tag. well then here's a solution for those that does 2005+ and happens to land on this page :)